# Regex pattern for Indian currency to validate

Tags: javascript, regex

I had the following pattern for currency validation .

```
/(?:^\d{1,3}(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?$)|(?:^\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$)/
```

Which Validates: `987,654,321.00`

I need a pattern where it should validate Indian number system like

```
98,76,54,321.00
```

I want to allow the user to enter commas and one dot.

I have few conditions.

1. I should allow users to enter commas also
2. The amount should not contain more than 2 decimal points.
3. The amount should validate Indian numeric pattern i.e `98,76,54,321.00` but not `987,654,321.00`
   I have referred the below link [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987550/regular-expression-for-indian-currency-validation-using-javascript) but not satisfies my requirement.I need  help in getting exact pattern
   Thanks,
   Karthik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for Indian Currency validation using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987550/regular-expression-for-indian-currency-validation-using-javascript)

Comment: It has nothing to do with AngularJS. You just need a regular expression and there are literally hundreds of links when you google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example & comments:

```
^(?:\d+|\d{1,2},(?:\d{2},)*\d{3})(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

**Javascript test snippet:**

```js
const reIndianCurry = /^(?:\d+|\d{1,2},(?:\d{2},)*\d{3})(?:\.\d{2})?$/;

console.log('-- Should Match:')
let arr = ['0.00', '123.00', '1,234.12', '12,34,56,789.00', '12,34,567', '123456', '12345.00'];
arr.forEach(function(s){console.log(reIndianCurry.test(s)+' : '+s)});

console.log('-- Should Not Match:')
arr = ['12,345,678.12', '12,34.00'];
arr.forEach(function(s){console.log(reIndianCurry.test(s)+' : '+s)});
```

Comment: Hi luke storms I should allow both With commas and without commas .So from your code I modified and using the below code .
/^(?:\d+|\d{1,2},(?:\d{2},)*\d{3})\.\d{2}|(?:\d+|\d{1,2},(?:\d{2},)*\d{3})$/
But this regex is allowing alphabets  after two decimals.

Comment: @karthik So the decimals are optional.  Notice the changes in the answer.