# Issue regarding regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate a string, something like this `2002 – 2004`. Please understand `–` is a special character and `–` is not equal to `-`. They are two different characters. I have tried some regular expressions.:

1. `^[0-9]+[ ]?[\\–]?[ ]?[0-9]*$`

Comment: You don't need `[]` around it, just use `–?` to match that optional character.

Comment: You can play here: https://regex101.com/r/za29Lc/1

Comment: Actually OP's specific char is an [en-dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html), the width of an N char

Comment: @mplungjan argh, I completely misread your comment - I thought you were asking what an em dash is, not asking if it's one. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not quite clear what the strings you want to validate. Here are a couple of examples.

To validate `2002 – 2004`:

```
\d{4}\s*–\s*\d{4}
```

For `1.23 M`:

```
\d\.\d{2}\s?M
```

I don’t understand the sequence `12,31,212` but perhaps:

```
\d+,\d+,\d+
// or
\d{2},\d{2},\d{3}
```

You can use the `{a,b}` to set up the quantity other than 0 or 1. Also, you can group different expressions by the `()` parenthesis.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for a complete explanation.

Comment: 12,31,212 is a Indian amount

Comment: Well, but I still don’t understand the format to be validated. How many digits are there between commas? Exactly two, two, three? It’s very interesting to search Wikipedia for “India amount”, but if he (or she) gave us a more descriptive source, we could write the precise expression to validate his (her) data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987550/regular-expression-for-indian-currency-validation-using-javascript